# Hide option in select based on other select value

Tags: javascript, html-select, hide

I have two select tags of arrival city and departure city for carpool web site, I want to prevent the user from selecting the same city in the select of arrival city and the select of the departure city.

Here is an example:

```html
<select name="departure" size="1">
  <option value="1">NY</option>
  <option value="2">FL</option>
  <option value="3">LA</option>
</select>

<select name="arrival" size="1">
  <option value="1">NY</option>
  <option value="2">FL</option>
  <option value="3">LA</option>
</select>
```

I just want to prevent the user from selecting the same city in both select fields using JavaScript or any other solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple solution, I'd suggest:

```
function deDupe(el) {
    var opt = el.selectedIndex,
        other = el.name == 'departure' ? document.getElementsByName('arrival')[0] : document.getElementsByName('departure')[0],
        options = other.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
        options[i].disabled = i == opt ? true : false;
    }
}

var departure = document.getElementsByName('departure')[0],
    arrival = document.getElementsByName('arrival')[0];

deDupe(document.getElementsByName('departure')[0]);

departure.onchange = function () {
    deDupe(departure);
};
arrival.onchange = function () {
    deDupe(arrival);
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qE4fN/).

References:

- [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName).
- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).

Comment: wow, thank you, it's really useful, except that the first option is always disabled because in the real select tags i have `<option value=""> Departure </option>` and in the second select I have `<option value=""> Arrival </option>` and with you solution the selected option is not the first empty one, but it's the first city

Comment: where can I add a condition to bypass the first option in each field because it's not a city field it's just indicators

Comment: The simplest, and most reliable approach, is to omit the function call on the document-ready/page-load event (the `deDupe(document.getElementsByName('departure')[0]);` call *outside* of the `onchange` event-handlers): [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qE4fN/1/).