# How to hide options of a select box using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am adding options dynamically  to a select box using the below function . I want to hide the option when they are added. They would be shown on special condition. Can I hide the option?

```
function loadName(name)
{

    var e=document.getElementById('templateName');
    var i =0;
    var abc = true;
    while(abc)
    {
        if (!e.options[i] || e.options[i].innerText==null)
        {
            abc =false;
        }
        else
        {
            i++
        }
    }
    e.options[i]= new Option(name ,name);

}

function loadName(name)
{

    var e=document.getElementById('templateName');
    var i =0;
    var abc = true;
    while(abc)
    {
        if (!e.options[i] || e.options[i].innerText==null)
        {
            abc =false;
        }
        else
        {
            i++
        }
    }
    e.options[i]= new Option(name ,name);

}
```

Actually there are three group of element which can be shown on basis of selection of other select box. My idea is to hide all and give a criteria on the basis of which it will be shown, else I will make three different select box hide them all and will the select box available on the choice if I can't hide individual options.

Comment: Hiding options will not be supported in IE, you can add/remove them or disable/enable them.  I would suggest adding that semi-colon on the `i++` lines

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide option in select based on other select value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101286/hide-option-in-select-based-on-other-select-value)

Comment: Instead of hiding/showing options, I prefer to store them in a javascript object/array then just empty/rebuild it every time. That way I know its cross browser and will always work